# OPENXML - Can not get the values what is wrong?

Tags: xml

I have problem with an XML statement, can not get the vaules from OPENXML. See my try below. What have I done wrong?

```
  `DECLARE @idoc int, @doc varchar(1000);   
    SET @doc ='
    <ROOT>
    <Tbl>
        <Entry>
            <One>ABC</One>
            <Two>DEF</Two>
            <Three>ABC</Three>
            <Four>DEF</Four>
            <Five>ABC</Five>
        </Entry>
    </Tbl>
    </ROOT>'

    --Create an internal representation of the XML document.  
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc;   

    -- SELECT stmt using OPENXML rowset provider  
    SELECT *  
    FROM   OPENXML (@idoc, '/ROOT/Tbl/Entry',2)   
             WITH (One     varchar(10)         '../@One',   
                   Two  varchar(10) '../@Two');
```

Comment: The right XPath relative to `/ROOT/Tbl/Entry` is `One`, `Two`. `../@One` would select an attribute node named `One` of the parent node of the `Entry`.

Comment: Do not get it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the change that [Martin Honner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen) is suggesting - it does work!

```
 SELECT *  
 FROM   OPENXML (@idoc, '/ROOT/Tbl/Entry',2)   
 WITH   ( One varchar(10) 'One',
          Two varchar(10) 'Two'
        );
```